# Broadcom chipset tx power

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I recently found an online guide about reducing electromagnetic radiation.Following the steps i get this output from     `sudo iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"pi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: 5A:55:28:42:8A:4E   
      Bit Rate=72 Mb/s   Tx-Power=1 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Are those values safe because i'm spending a lot of hours with my laptop.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey! I was just messing around with my txpower and found out that you can set it even lower... I used `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 0` which sets txpower to 1mW. That's as low as I can get it (-values not allowed on my card). If you really want to minimize exposure, you should probably use the lowest level that is still functional. Great question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your tx-power is very low (1dBm). The most restrictive international standard is set at 20dBm or roughly 100mW. Right now, you are at about 1% or 1.25mW

In the United States and in Canada, the limit is set to 37dBm which is roughly 5W!

I would also recommend adjusting the txpower of your wireless router. If this setting is not available on your router, use a different firmware. Although, I'm pretty sure the linksys txpower is pretty low like 40 or 70mW.

Also, you can set the txpower even lower so long as it is still functional:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 0
```

The setting above will equal 1mW

Comment: online dBm to mW converter http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/dBm_to_mW.htm